# Equation does not start at the begining of the second line

Tags: math-mode, floats, line-breaking, mathtools

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{mutual}
\begin{multlined}
I(Predicted;Actual)=\sum \limits_{a,b} p(Predicted,Actual)\log \frac{p(Predited,Actual}{p(Predicted)p(Actual)}\\
=\log \frac{p(Predicted,Actual)}{p(Predicted)p(Actual)}
\end{multlined}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Considering the above code: I would like the `=log ...` to be at the beginning of the new line but it does not follow my expectation.

How do I fix it?

Comment: `multlined` is not desifned for that.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg maybe not but since his/her answer was way earlier and worked just fine for me, so I accepted that.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should always accept the _best_ answer, not the first acceptable one.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thought `best` is interpreted as `most useful to the OP`, which I guess might mean `worked and available before my deadline!`

Comment: @cfr to be honest that only meant this Computer science principle: FIFO (Fitst In First Out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the `split` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{mutual}
  \begin{split}
    I(Predicted;Actual)&=\sum \limits_{a,b} p(Predicted,Actual)\log \frac{p(Predited,Actual}{p(Predicted)p(Actual)}\\
                       &=\log \frac{p(Predicted,Actual)}{p(Predicted)p(Actual)}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

Note the use of the alignment character `&` to align the `=` sign in both lines.

Comment: The words should be inside `\mathrm`

Comment: @egreg `\mathrm` rather than `\text` because `Predicted` etc. are mathematical function-like?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would do it, using the `align*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  I(\mathrm{Predicted}; \mathrm{Actual})
  &= \sum_{a,b}p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual}) \log\frac{p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual})}{p(\mathrm{Predicted}) p(\mathrm{Actual})}\\
  &= \log\frac{p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual})}{p(\mathrm{Predicted}) p(\mathrm{Actual})}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

An alternative solution is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &I(\mathrm{Predicted}; \mathrm{Actual})\\
  &= \sum_{a,b}p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual}) \log\frac{p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual})}{p(\mathrm{Predicted}) p(\mathrm{Actual})}\\
  &= \log\frac{p(\mathrm{Predicted}, \mathrm{Actual})}{p(\mathrm{Predicted}) p(\mathrm{Actual})}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

The reason for using the latter is, that the white space below `I(\mathrm{Predicted}; \mathrm{Actual})` is removed.

P.S. There is no need for the `\limits` operator in your case.

Comment: What `=` do you mean? for the limits, I just got used to use it even when there is an alternative for that and for the `;`, the equation is like that. `I(A;B)` stands for the mutual information while `p(A,B)` stands for the probability of A and B co-occur. So there are different things but thanks for the kind consideration.

Comment: A and B to be co-occurred* (had to make another comment to correct myself cause the `stackexchange` did not allow me to edit the previous comment.

Comment: @user3049183 I didn't knew about the `;` and `,` so fair enough. `:-)` I mean the `=` at the end of the first line, as I wrote...

Comment: To be honest I still can not find the `=` at the end of first line, Maybe it is differently rendered in your system as in my side, the equation at the question only has two lines, there is no `=` at the end of first line but at the middle.

Comment: @user3049183 Wauw! I have no idea what's going on with me; for some reason I mistook Sebastiano's answer for the question. SORRY!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Don't be worry. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have made some changes. Now I think it's fine. If you prefer to have the number of equation, remove `\nonumber`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\label{mutual}
\begin{align}
I(\text{Predicted};\text{Actual}) &=\sum \limits_{a,b} p(\text{Predicted},\text{Actual})\log \frac{p(\text{Predicted},\text{Actual})}{p(\text{Predicted})p(\text{Actual})}= \nonumber &&\\ 
&= \log \frac{p(\text{Predicted},\text{Actual})}{p(\text{Predicted})p(\text{Actual})}\nonumber
\end{align}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `flalign`. A simple `align` is better, in general.

Comment: Always I accept the advice, especially yours, that you are well prepared, and the first in the standings.

Comment: I don't think you want the extra `=` at the end of the first line, do you? What does `\label{mutual}` do?

Comment: @cfr Honestly, at least here in Sicily, `=` it puts the end to the beginning when you go to the head. I have copy `\label{mutual}` from the question. I do not know just that command.

Comment: But you know the OP doesn't want the extra `=` as it isn't included in the original example. `\label{mutual}` there is pointless. It cannot possibly do anything useful.